# Find count of all such distinct tuples, (i, j, k) where (i*j)%k == 0

Tags: algorithm, combinations, counting, number-theory

Given a number `n`. How to find the count of all such distinct tuples?

`(i, j, k)` where `(i*j)%k == 0,` where `1<=i<=n, 1<=j<=n, 1<=k<=n` in `O(n^2)` or better.

Comment: Where are your thoughts and efforts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Store counts of i*j pairs in hashtable/map/array
2. Do something like sieve to count all multiples of k in frequency array

Sample code:

```
vector<int>freq(n*n+1); //that's just array of n*n+1 zeroes

for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
    freq[i*j]++;

int cnt = 0;
for(int k=1; k<=n; k++)
    for(int j=0; j<=n*n; j+=k) //note these loops look like n^3 at first glance yet it's something like n^2 log n (check harmonic number if you're curious why)
    cnt+=freq[j];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think complexity is (n^2 log*n) because  n^2 * (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... 1/n)  approximates to n^2 * (logn)

Comment: You should be able to do `for(int j = k;  j <= n * n;  j += k)` as position zero is always set to zero.